# autoPaging in jsPdf .html() method

Tags: jspdf

I have updated jsPdf to version "jspdf": "^2.4.0", and saw an option called autoPaging in the html() method of jspdf, anyone knows what is it used for ? I tried using it but didnt see anything different on the generated pdf.

I am guessing it might be related to paging like "Page 1 of 2".

Answer (score 2):

As jspdf documentation:

Autopaging is used to set the auto paging mode.

false: Auto paging is disabled.

true or 'slice': Will cut shapes or text chunks across page breaks. Will possibly slice text in half, making it difficult to read.

'text': Trys not to cut text in half across page breaks. Works best for documents consisting mostly of a single column of text.

Default is true.